# Why is $(-1)^p$, where, $0<p<1$ is a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Why is $(-1)^p$, where, $0<p<1$ is a complex number?

If $p = \frac{1}{4}$, then $(-1)^{p}=(-1)^\frac{1}{4}=((-1)^{4})^\frac{1}{16}=(1)^{1/16}=1$

However, apparently $(-1)^\frac{1}{4}=a+ai$, where $a=0.707107$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Not always true; if you mean a Complex, non-Real number $(-1)^{1/3}=-1 $

Comment: What you are missing is that the "rule", $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, doesn't apply to negative values of $a$. E.g., $((-1)^{1/2})^2=-1$, but $((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your fundamental assumption that $a^b = (a^c)^{b/c}$ is not true. For example, if you stick in $p = 1$ in your case, your argument shows that
$$ -1 = 1, $$
which is very much not true. For positive real numbers, that you can distribute exponents in whatever way you want. But not so for negative real numbers (or complex numbers).

In fact, one has to be very precise to even say what $(-1)^p$ even means. What does it mean? We give it the meaning
$$ a^p = e^{p \log a}, $$
and for complex or negative $a$ we note that we refer to (a branch of) the complex logarithm function.

Answer (score 1):

For any real number $x,$ we can assign a reasonable value 
$$  (-1)^x = \cos \pi x + i \sin \pi x  $$
This comes from the choice $\log (-1) = i \pi$

For irrational $x,$ we get an infinite number of distinct values along with the one I display above, such as
$$  (-1)^x = \cos 3\pi x + i \sin 3\pi x,  $$
$$  (-1)^x = \cos 5\pi x + i \sin 5\pi x,  $$
so on forever along with the complex conjugates of these. The entire collection is then dense in the unit circle.

If $x$ is rational, we get a finite number of values, equally spaced around the unit circle. As it was mentioned, the three cube roots of $-1$ are
$$  -1, \; \; \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}, \; \;  \frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}. $$

Meanwhile, if $x = 1/n$ with odd integer $n,$ we generally take 
$-1$
as the value. I've always thought this a bit problematic because we get something else for $(-1)^{2/(2n)}$